# Django says 'QuerySet' has no object 'choice_query', but the website using the same object reaches them

Tags: python, django

Following the Django tutorial, I was thinking about adding a functionality wherein the user will be informed if there were no choices to be voted on regarding a particular question. However, the shell is throwing errors left and right and I know for a fact that this object indeed is real, as the webpage that's supposed to print out the choices is doing its job (and using the object that Django insists is non-existant), so I am very curious as to why the Django shell dismisses the reality of the object.

Here are the shell commands I attempted, and its subsequent failure:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> q = Question.objects.filter(pk=1)
>>> q.choice_set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'choice_set'
```

Here is the file polls/templates/polls/detail.html (which also works as it should, par the if empty_choice statement, it prints nothing at all)

```
<h1> {{ question.question_text }} </h1>

{% if error_message %}<p> <strong> {{ error_message }} </strong> </p> {% endif %}
{% if empty_choice %}
        <p> There are no choices!  </p>
{% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"
                        value="{{ choice.id }}"/>
                        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
                        <br />
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
        </form>
{% endif %}
```

and here is the polls/views.py (for the vote portion)

```
def vote(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
                selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
                empty_choice = question.choice_set.exists()
        except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
                # Redisplay the question voting form.
                return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                        'question': question,
                        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice!",
                        })
        else:
                selected_choice.votes += 1
                selected_choice.save()
                # Always return HttpResonseRedirect after POST success, prevents
                # data from being posted twice if someone hits the back button!
                return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id, )) )
```

As mentioned, the webpage will show me the choices to every question (granted their existence) and no other errors are being thrown. It is only the "if empty_choice" and the shell that is not co-operating.

EDIT: I've read someone else's suggestion to delete the models.pyc file, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `QuerySet` is plural - it represents what might be multiple instances of the model class. Although it's not an exact parallel, it can be useful to think of a queryset as representing a list of instances. You've used a primary key filter, which will return at most one element unless something unusual is going on, but the return type from `filter` doesn't change based on that. You need to either use `get` (which returns a single instance or raises an exception if nothing matches the arguments) or index into it with `q[0]` or something similar. In all cases you need to decide what you want to do on requests that don't match a record - [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) is one obvious choice.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! It Works wonderfully!
But, why does the following code work?
`selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])`
It gets the Choice_set from the question without indexing it.

Comment: `get` returns a single instance of the model, or raises an exception if nothing matches.

Comment: I should have said, `get` also raises a different exception if more than one record matches. Which is generally not a concern with `pk` filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get the choice_set by looping on the queryset.

you do `q[0].choice_set` to get the first element or
you can loop on views by:

```
q = Question.objects.filter(pk=1)
```

`for x in q:
   print(x.choice_set)`

Comment: Thanks, I am sure I tried that, but after I tried it again, it worked! :)